# Generating CDKey works, checking if exists doesnt

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my code.
The first one works, it will generate a cdkey and enter it to the mysql db.

```
<?
function createRandomKey($amount)
{
    $keyset = "abcdefghijklmABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $randkey = "";
    for ($i=0; $i<$amount; $i++)
    $randkey .= substr($keyset, rand(0, strlen($keyset)-1), 1);
    return $randkey;
}

if($_POST['post_true'] == "true")
{
    $randomkey = createRandomKey(20);
    query(" INSERT INTO cdkeys (`cdkey`,`used`,`user_id`) VALUES (' ".escapeadmin($randomkey)."', '".escapeadmin(0)."', '".escapeadmin(0)." ') ");
    echo "<b>Generated Key:</b> ";
    echo $randomkey;
}
?>
```

it will rand different numbers and characters, a-z0-9, the cdkey length is 20 chars.

the second code is the one for checking if the cdkey exists in the databse.

```
<?
        // FETCH POSTED CDKEY
        $postedkey = $_POST['cdkey'];
        $sql_check_cdkey = query("SELECT * FROM cdkeys WHERE cdkey = '".escape($postedkey)."' ");
        $qry_check_cdkey = mysql_fetch_array($sql_check_cdkey);

        if(mysql_num_rows($sql_check_cdkey) == "0") { red("Wrong CD Key Entered"); echo $_POST['cdkey']; }
        else
        {
            echo "exists, magic time";
        }
?>
```

now the problem is, that whenever i enter the key , lets say:
736KhYDmZhm1G1P72Ja5HIUg4VcBd9
that is in the databse (i checked, and the generator even echo the key for me)
the key cannot be find. i always get cd key don't exists message.
the key is there, but it's just not finding it.
i tried to change the key from the numbers and characters to "testkey123" and when i tried to search, it worked this time.

it seems like it cant find it as random characters.
what am i missing? i really need to fix it.
thank you

Comment: Is your column able to save such a long string?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM cdkeys` , verify the data there is what you are expecting.

Comment: matteo , yes. Digital, can you explain more? sorry

Comment: @user3151178: When you add the key you are using escapeadmin() and when you try to retrieve it you are using escape(). Please post those functions...

Comment: What is the `query` function logic? More specifically, what is it returning? Can you dump the contents of `$sql_check_cdkey`?

Answer (score 0):

Your test string '736KhYDmZhm1G1P72Ja5HIUg4VcBd9' is 30 characters long - but you say that "cdkey length is 20 chars". You are probably truncating the string when you store it.

Change the size of the column that stores the string:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE cdkey cdkey varchar(100)
```